# Ubuntu ARM ldd can't find libs

Tags: arm

I have a program that compiled fine on Ubuntu ARM (12.04) but it cannot run due to linking errrs. e.g. libX11.so.6 cannot be found, however it is clearly in

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf

ldconfig -v shows it as well
```

What's weird is when I pass LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/arm-gnueabihf/ to ldd (after the shared library), I get the message

```
ldd: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/: No such file or directory
```

While the directory clearly exists. What could be going wrong? I ran sudo ldconfig.

Comment: How did you compile the program? With what compiler and what options?

Answer (score 1):

You may have mixed [ABIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). There are currently several ABIs for ARM processors in common use, due to the variety in ARM CPUs. Check that you have a [gnueabihf](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=8758) binary, and not a gnueabi binary. You can install both kinds of binaries on the same system, but you can't link both kinds of libraries inside a single executable. It's like 32-bit and 64-bit executables on x86 systems.

With `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the right command to add the variable in the environment for the duration of the `ldd` command is

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ ldd /path/to/binary
```

You wrote `ldd LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ /path/to/binary` which tells `ldd` to act on a file called `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/`.

Comment: I think you're right, it has something to do with mixed ABI's. I added -mfloat-abi=softfp to gcc, it won't compile without it. But now it won't link. I suppose my system libs are hardfp. Can I install the softfp versions or do I need to switch to a softfp distro?

Comment: @RobbR You can install both on the same system. I think it's supposed to work on Ubuntu now (`apt-get install packagename:armel`), but I have no experience (I do arm and I do Ubuntu but I don't do Ubuntu on arm).